# How to print word get from variable in specific line with AWK?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I wish print in the "END" of the second line(or also in the end the file) a specific word get from a variable.
it would be appreciated to have both methods.

I have a file `my_file.txt` with this content:

```
#Insert the names separeted by space     
l.lovre p.jhonson p.backer t.thompson q.ward
```

I tried to coding right so:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=/path/my_file.txt

read -p "Insert name: " name

#my attempt
awk -v myvar="$name" 'END{print myvar}' $filename
 
echo 'Name added'
```

But doesn't work

I would get this result:

my_file.txt:

```
#Insert the names separeted by space     
l.lovre p.jhonson p.backer t.thompson q.ward **name**
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` is simpler:

```
sed -i "$ s/$/ $name/" my_file.txt
```

Edit: Make sure the last line in the file is not empty.

Comment: and make sure that `$name` doesn't contain `/` or `&` or `\1` or any of multiple other strings. sed only looks simpler while a sed solution that's as robust as an awk solution is much harder to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You could add it to the whole line at line 2 in the file with `$0 = $0 FS myvar` and keep your `END` block to print it after all the lines since you want that too. If you don't want it after all the lines, remove the `END` block.

```
awk -v myvar="$name" 'FNR==2 {$0 = $0 FS myvar}1; END{print myvar}' $filename
```

Output with `name=Michele`:

```
#Insert the names separeted by space
l.lovre p.jhonson p.backer t.thompson q.ward Michele
Michele
```

Answer (score 2):

By default `awk` does not *update* the file.  If you want to update the file you have a couple options:

```
######
# write to tmp file and then overwrite original file with tmp file

awk -v myvar="$name" 'END{print myvar}' "$filename" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$filename"

######
# if using 'GNU awk' you can use '-i inplace' to modify the file

awk -i inplace -v myvar="$name" 'END{print myvar}' "$filename"
```

As for the issue of appending the new name onto the end of the 2nd line, or creating a new line if there are no names in the current file: one idea:

```
######
# writing to tmp file

awk -v myvar="$name" 'FNR==2 { print $0,myvar; added=1; next} 1; END { if (added!=1) print myvar}' "$filename" > tmpfile
mv tmpfile "$filename"

######
# using 'GNU awk'

awk -i inplace -v myvar="$name" 'FNR==2 { print $0,myvar; added=1; next} 1; ENDFILE { if (added!=1) print myvar}' "$filename"
```

**NOTES:**

- all input lines need to be echoed to stdout in order for them to 'remain' in the file, hence the standalone `1`
- `END {}` block processing takes place *after* a file has been processed; any output generated by the `END {}` block will go to stdout
- if using `GNU awk` we have access to the `ENDFILE {}` block which is, in essence, the same as an `END {}` block except that processing in this case *does* apply to the file

Taking the `GNU awk` solution for a test drive:

```
$ filename=names.dat
$ cat "$filename"
# Insert the names separeted by space

$ name='b.bunny'
$ awk -i inplace -v myvar="$name" 'FNR==2 { print $0,myvar; added=1; next} 1; ENDFILE { if (added!=1) print myvar}' "$filename"
$ cat "$filename"
# Insert the names separeted by space
b.bunny

$ name='d.duck'
$ awk -i inplace -v myvar="$name" 'FNR==2 { print $0,myvar; added=1; next} 1; ENDFILE { if (added!=1) print myvar}' "$filename"
$ cat "$filename"
# Insert the names separeted by space
b.bunny d.duck
```

Comment: Add `&&` between `> "$tmpfile" and `mv ...` so you don't zap your input file if there's a failure in awk or writing to the tmp file.